# How can I display footer with scrollbarV = True in Angular 8?

Tags: html, css, angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable to display the data.I need the limit the height of data table & display the vertical scrollbar. Below is my configuration for table

I tried limiting the height of the data table using scss as

```
     .ngx-datatable {
     height: 250px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     }
```

```
                <ngx-datatable 
                    class="bootstrap"
                    [rows]="rows"
                    [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
                    [columns]="columns" 
                    [columnMode]="'force'" 
                    [headerHeight]="5" 
                    [footerHeight]="20"
                    [rowHeight]="30"
                    [reorderable]="reorderable" 
                    [scrollbarH]="true"
                    [scrollbarV]="true" 
                    [selected]="selected"
                    [selectionType]="'single'" 
                    (activate)="onActivate($event)"
                    (select)="onSelect($event)"
                    >
                       <ngx-datatable-footer></ngx-datatable-footer>
                       <ngx-datatable-column name="Survey Name" 
                              style="vertical-align:middle;">
                          <ng-template let-row="row" 
                              ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                              {{row.company }}
                            </ng-template>
                          </ngx-datatable-column>
               </ngx-datatable>
```

I am not able to display both vertical scroll bar & footer at the same time.
My Footer and last rows in grid are not showed at all

Can someone help to find where i am doing it wrong[image]

Comment: This is happening even on Angular 7. I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In css file, set min-height

```
ngx-datatable { min-height: 200px; }
```

set ScrollbarV property to 'auto'

```
[scrollbarV]="auto"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).